# Visual Basic Script Abstract Class and Interface

Tags: oop, vbscript

If this is the simple class on VBScript:

```
Class Information
  'Create a private property to hold the phone number
  Private strPhoneNumber
End Class
```

How can i use Abstract Class and Interface in VBScript?

Comment: You can't it's a ["Scripting Language"](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Scripting_language).

Comment: @Lankymart but if language supports oop, it should support the principle of polymorphism

Comment: It's a "cut-down" form of VB, you want true OOP you need to use [tag:vb6] or [tag:vb.net]. VBScript doesn't purport to be OOP it's actually more an "Object Based" rather than fully "Object Oriented" language.